# Multiplication in $S_4$ with cycle notation and permutation matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-matrices

> Solve the equation $(23)x^{-1}(124)=(34)^4$ in $S_4$.

I'm a bit confused about which way I should go when multiplying. Using cycle notation I've been told to go from right to left, but I find it much easier to do these using matrix notation. So I write the equation as $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ &&&\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 2&4&3&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}$$ since I figured out that $(34)^4=(1)$.

Now I need to figure out what to put in the blank spots. Going from left to right I figured that  I need to have $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 4&3&1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 2&4&3&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}$$

but when going from right to left I ended up with

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 4&1&2&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 2&4&3&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\ 1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}$$ which is wrong. Why is the multiplication reversed in this case?

Comment: We have $x^{-1}=(23)(142)$ by directly multiplying the equation with $(23)^{-1}=(23)$ from the left and with $(124)^{-1}=(142)$ from the right. So $x=(124)(23)$.

Comment: Comment on "easier with matrix notation". The two methods are indeed equivalent, so either will do for calculation. But cycle notation calls for a lot less writing and displays properties of permutations in more obvious form, so if you have  more than a little calculation work to do it pays to learn cycle notation. In the long run it's much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that $(34)^4=e.$

What I would do next is take the inverse of the whole of the LHS, since $(ab^{-1}c)^{-1}=c^{-1}ba^{-1}$; thus

$$(124)^{-1}x(23)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e,$$

which gives

$$\begin{align}
x&=(124)e(23)\\
&=(1234)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}$$

whose inverse is

$$x^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix},$$

so *you were right; you just forgot to take inverses.*